# Airflow to disable "delete DAGs" option from airflow UI

Tags: airflow

Is there any parameter can be configured to restrict users not to delete any of the DAGs from UI?
Or Disable the DELTE button?

Comment: it doesn't seem like this is an option (see here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=user%20permissions). Could you update your question to include the type of authentication you have enabled (if any)?

Comment: @ PirateNinjas Thanks for your response. I have currently authenticating via Okta to specific users. But they all have admin access be default. Okta can't provide role based access control.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are on another role other than Admin,
you can remove the `can delete on Airflow` permission from the role.

[image: can delete on Airflow permission]

While the button will still be visible, they will get permissions denied when trying to delete a DAG.